# facebook HTTP feed in PHP returning Array and not JSON

Tags: php, json, vb.net, facebook-graph-api

Hey all I have the following PHP script that gathers some information from the facebook API:

```
$request = (new FacebookRequest(
    $session, 'GET', '/me/home'
));

$response           = $request->execute();
$graphObject        = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
print_r($graphObject);
```

However, the output of that looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => xxxxxxx78552_74905xxxxxxxx
                [from] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [id] => 72xxxxxx05xxxx52
                        [name] => Tom xxxxxx
                    )

                [story] => Tom xxxx shared xxxxx xxxxx's status update.
                [story_tags] => stdClass Object
       etc etc....
```

I know why I am getting an array **(asArray();)** but I need to convert it over to JSON. I try doing this via VB.net's JSON.net:

```
result = mainPage.theNewsFeed
objWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & "\home.json", False, Encoding.UTF8)
objWriter.Write(JSONDeserialize(result).ToString)
objWriter.Close()
```

That code above produces this error:

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: A. Path '', line 0, position 0.

on the line:

```
objWriter.Write(JSONDeserialize(result).ToString)
```

Which I can understand since its not in the correct json format.

How can I convert it over either using PHP or VB.net to get it into the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

Well to output an array as JSON in PHP you want to use it's json_encode function and use your array as the parameter. It'll return a JSON string.

```
$json = json_encode($graphObject);
```

I've no experience with VB.net but I'm assuming you're using the wrong method.

Serialize means that an object or array will be converted to a string representation (like JSON).
Deserialize means that a string will be converted to objects or arrays.

So the method you're using is actually expecting a JSON instead of creating it.